# How to loop through sql and print output time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way I can loop through my SQL Server table and write out to a text file how long it takes to delete let's say every 10,000 rows?

```
DELETE FROM ORDERS o
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c
    ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE ActiveDt < '03/03/2001'    

DELETE FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE ActiveDt < '03/03/2001'
```

Comment: If all you want is a benchmark, would there be anything wrong with just observing the time the entire delete query took, then dividing by the number of records to deleted to get an effective time per record?

Comment: You would need to do something like delete top 10 and put that inside a while exists. I would change the number to something greater than 10 though as the time should be absurdly fast to delete 10 rows at a time. I have to ask though, what are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @SeanLange --- you are correct as 10 would be fairly fast to notice anything. I've changed it to at least 10,000 rows. For testing purposes, I am trying to see how long it takes to execute the rows by printing out to let's say a text file. I dont want to define top 10, etc. I just want it to delete 10,000 rows, write the time out, then continue the deletion.

Comment: Right I understand what you are trying to do. But to what end? What do you hope to gain here? Remember that deleting 10,000 rows is not the same amount of time it would take to delete 100,000 as a single batch. The amount of logging will affect the time also.

Comment: is it not in theory a single transaction? so delete FROM xxxx deletes all n rows in t seconds, maybe there isn't really a question of 'how many have you deleted so far'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE  @TS AS datetime;
DECLARE @CNT int;

lab:
SET @TS = getdate();
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT TOP 10000 * from CustTable)
    DELETE CTE ;

SET @CNT = @@rowcount;

PRINT DATEDIFF(millisecond, @TS, getdate());  --write away somewhere if required 

If @CNT > 0
    GOTO lab
```

you could use spWriteStringToFile to push data to a text file

Comment: I dont want to define "Top 10000". Just straight delete, print out time, continue on with delete.

Comment: but you want to delete a particular 10,000 rows at a time - is that right?  My idea is to grab the first 10,000 rows in no particular order, then delete them.  Oh I see, you want a sort of asynchronous running output of time data - sorry I don't know how to do it in SQL, there may be performance tools or a flag on SQL command line execute - but I don't know, sorry!